# How can I use XML Schema regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, xsd

I have a 2 part question:

1. How can I get the `regex` expression of an `XSD` facet and then use it to determine if a string matches the restriction? In my mind, this is "How do I convert XML Schema regex to .NET `Regex`", but I'm open for suggestions if you have another way for me to do it other than converting the expression.
2. If the test (#1) fails, how can I use the `XSD` pattern `regex` to automatically create a string which does satisfy the constraint?

Comment: You cannot work with XML (reliably) using a regular expression. Can you provide more detail, such as what kind of validation or regex parsing are you wanting to do?

Comment: Grab the regex from an XSD (eg, <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]"/>), and use it within .NET with a normal string value ("ABC").

Comment: Why not just validate the XML against the schemas?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, in general it could be a custom form collecting data; a field level validation, where the field is mapped to a specific simple content in an XSD. Imagine that validation done near-as-you- type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [XmlSchemaDatatype.ParseValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4t690ysw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is your answer. Assuming the associated simple type has more facets and you only want to validate against the pattern one(s), then you have to simply find the enumeration facet in the [XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction.Facets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemasimpletyperestriction.facets%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), use a copy of that to create a new XmlSchemaSimpleType, with a new XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemasimpletype.content%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and new [pattern facet(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemapatternfacet%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) using the values you scooped above. Then using this newly created simple type, invoke XmlSchemaDatatype.ParseValue.

   I would advise against your suggestion in the comment, since the regex "dialects" are different.
2. I am not aware of such a thing, available for free or otherwise. I am sure it can be done but I never found something that would actually work, when I needed it myself. If you do find one, please share.

Comment: this seems promising! I'll try to see if it works in my application. Do you know if inherited pattern facets are properly applied with XmlSchemaDatatype.ParseValue?

Answer (score 1):

It is not too difficult to convert a XML Schema regex to a .NET regex.

Basically you need to replace few patterns such as \c and \D with by their .NET alternatives such as \p{_xmlC} and \P{_xmlD}.

Also you need to wrap expression in ^ and $ markers.

.NET implements this in method Preprocess in https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Xml/System/Xml/Schema/FacetChecker.cs

If you decide to copy-paste the implementation, be careful, though.

You need to replace loop

`for (int position = 0; position < length - 2; position ++)`

with

`for (int position = 0; position < length - 1; position ++)`

because for optimization reasons Preprocess assumes the input expression is enclosed in parentheses.